# Error custom JavaScript is not allowed in AMP

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I created a new amp project, but after importing `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>`, an error is reported and custom JavaScript is not allowed!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>demo3</title>
        <meta name='detion' content="hello demo3" />
    
        <link rel="canonical" href="demo3.html">
        <link rel="amphtml" href="index.html">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="amp_favicon.png">
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        
        
        <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
        <noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <button type="button">hello</button>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the JS? where is the JS authorization ID?

Comment: It's his own core“ ampproject.org/v0 . JS ", and then use" #development = 1 "to verify the prompt. Custom JavaScript is not allowed

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has been solved; the solution is to mount this website to the server